# Instagram login error : Invalid Client Secret

Tags: php

If I am trying to login with Instagram using api,

Code :

```
$ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $apiHost);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($apiData));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($apiData));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $jsonData = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

Error :

```
{
error_type: "OAuthException",
code: 400,
error_message: "Invalid Client Secret"
}
```

Does any one have idea?

Comment: You supply  invalid  client secret

Comment: @MASIDDIQUI : But I have copyed secret from developer account and passed into request then how it is invalid..?

Comment: check if you have any white spaces in that

Comment: @MASIDDIQUI : Yes, thank man you saved my time

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment: check if there is white space when you copied it.

But in my case removing the white space still didn't fix the error. Instead I tried writing it directly and that seemed to do the trick.